# Unable to run dev container

Tags: docker, debian, vscode-devcontainer

I'm trying to run Haskell Dev Environment with the following config and `Dockerfile`

**devcontainer.json**

```
{
  "name": "Haskell (Community)",
  "build": {
    "dockerfile": "Dockerfile"
  },
  "runArgs": [
    "--network",
    "host"
  ],
  // Configure tool-specific properties.
  "customizations": {
    // Configure properties specific to VS Code.
    "vscode": {
      // Set *default* container specific settings.json values on container create.
      "settings": {
        "haskell.manageHLS": "GHCup",
        "remote.containers.logLevel": "verbose"
      },
      // Add the IDs of extensions you want installed when the container is created.
      "extensions": [
        "haskell.haskell"
      ]
    }
  },
  // Comment out to connect as root instead. To add a non-root user, see: https://aka.ms/vscode-remote/containers/non-root.
  "remoteUser": "vscode"
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM debian:bullseye-slim

ENV LANG C.UTF-8

# [Option] Install zsh
ARG INSTALL_ZSH="true"
# [Option] Upgrade OS packages to their latest versions
ARG UPGRADE_PACKAGES="false"

# Install needed packages and setup non-root user.
# Use a separate RUN statement to add your own dependencies
ARG USERNAME=vscode
ARG USER_UID=1000
ARG USER_GID=$USER_UID
COPY library-scripts/*.sh /tmp/library-scripts/
RUN apt-get update --fix-missing \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install gnupg \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list \
    && apt-get update \
    # Uncomment to test connectivity
    # && apt-get install -y iputils-ping \
    # && ping deb.debian.org \
    && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive \
    && /bin/bash /tmp/library-scripts/common-debian.sh "${INSTALL_ZSH}" "${USERNAME}" "${USER_UID}" "${USER_GID}" "${UPGRADE_PACKAGES}" "true" "true"\
    && rm -rf /tmp/library-scripts \
    && apt-get install -o Acquire::http::Timeout=300 -y --no-install-recommends \
        dpkg-dev \
        gcc \
        libc6-dev \
        libffi-dev \
        libgmp-dev \
        libnuma-dev \
        libtinfo-dev \
        zlib1g-dev \
    && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install latest GHCup in the non-root user home
USER $USERNAME

RUN mkdir -p "$HOME/.ghcup/bin" \
    && curl -LJ "https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghcup/x86_64-linux-ghcup" -o "$HOME/.ghcup/bin/ghcup" \
    && chmod +x "$HOME/.ghcup/bin/ghcup"
ENV PATH="/home/$USERNAME/.cabal/bin:/home/$USERNAME/.ghcup/bin:$PATH"

# [Choice] GHC version: recommended, latest, 9.2, 9.0, 8.10, 8.8, 8.6
ARG GHC_VERSION="latest"

# Use GHCup to install versions of main utilities
# If you prefer to let the Haskell extension install everything on demand,
# comment out the lines below. In that case, you may need to manually run "cabal update""."
RUN ghcup install ghc "${GHC_VERSION}" --set \
    && ghcup install cabal recommended --set \
    && ghcup install stack recommended --set \
    && ghcup install hls recommended --set \
    && cabal update
```

However, it throws:

```
[302 ms] Dev Containers 0.288.1 in VS Code 1.77.3 (704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710).
[300 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[603 ms] Setting up container for folder or workspace: d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world
[609 ms] Start: Run: wsl -l -v
[1069 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c echo ~
[2560 ms] Start: Run: wsl -d Ubuntu -e /bin/sh -c cd '/home/Quarks' && /bin/sh
[2936 ms] Start: Run in host: id -un
[3482 ms] Quarks
[3483 ms] 
[3485 ms] Start: Run in host: cat /etc/passwd
[3495 ms] Start: Run in host: echo ~
[3502 ms] /home/Quarks
[3503 ms] 
[3506 ms] Start: Run in host: test -x '/home/Quarks/.vscode-remote-containers/bin/704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710/node'
[3511 ms] 
[3512 ms] 
[3517 ms] Start: Run in host: test -f '/home/Quarks/.vscode-remote-containers/dist/vscode-remote-containers-server-0.288.1.js'
[3523 ms] 
[3524 ms] 
[3555 ms] userEnvProbe: loginInteractiveShell (default)
[3556 ms] userEnvProbe: not found in cache
[3559 ms] userEnvProbe shell: /bin/bash
[5571 ms] Start: Run in Host: /bin/sh 
[5605 ms] Start: Run in container: for pid in `cd /proc && ls -d [0-9]*`; do { echo $pid ; readlink /proc/$pid/cwd || echo ; readlink /proc/$pid/ns/mnt || echo ; cat /proc/$pid/stat | tr "
[7744 ms] userEnvProbe is taking longer than 2 seconds. Process tree:
  832: /bin/bash -lic echo -n 0caa9016-b320-4e3e-821f-5b51cc6f575a; cat /proc/self/environ; echo -n 0caa9016-b320-4e3e-821f-5b51cc6f575a 
    845: /bin/sh /usr/sbin/update-motd --show-only 
      846: run-parts --lsbsysinit /etc/update-motd.d 
        852: /bin/sh /etc/update-motd.d/50-landscape-sysinfo 
          859: /usr/bin/python3 /usr/bin/landscape-sysinfo 
[12005 ms] userEnvProbe PATHs:
Probe:     '/home/Quarks/.local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/usr/lib/wsl/lib:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio/2019/Community/VC/Tools/MSVC/14.29.30133/bin/Hostx64/x64:/mnt/c/Build/graalvm-ce-java17-21.3.3.1/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Programs/Microsoft VS Code/bin:/mnt/c/tools/dart-sdk/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Roaming/Pub/Cache/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/HP/Common/HPDestPlgIn/:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts:/mnt/c/tools/batch:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Programs/oh-my-posh/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Roaming/npm:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/WebStorm 2019.2.4/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2.4/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/CLion 2019.2.5/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/GitHubDesktop/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2022.3.2/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Pandoc/:/mnt/c/Program Files/JetBrains/PyCharm Community Edition 2022.3.3/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python310/Scripts/:/mnt/c/Build/apache-maven-3.8.4/bin:/mnt/c/Program Files/nodejs:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey:/mnt/c/Program Files/Git/bin:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Program Files/heroku/bin:/mnt/c/tools/platform-tools:/mnt/c/WINDOWS:/mnt/c/ProgramData/chocolatey/bin:/mnt/c/ghcup/bin:/Docker/host/bin:/mnt/c/Users/Quarks/AppData/Roaming/local/bin:/snap/bin'
Container: None
[12112 ms] Start: Run in Host: wslpath -w /mnt/wslg/runtime-dir/wayland-0
[12272 ms] Start: Check Docker is running
[12273 ms] Start: Run: docker version --format {{.Server.APIVersion}}
[14233 ms] Server API version: 1.41
[14239 ms] Start: Run: docker volume ls -q
[15998 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=vsch.local.folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --filter label=vsch.quality=stable
[17805 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[19616 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world
[20840 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world
[21755 ms] Start: Run: C:\Users\Quarks\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\Quarks\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-dd392877-a03c-41f6-93bd-5777b1a35b8f1681747497325 --workspace-folder d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --id-label devcontainer.config_file=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-70e6c119-04ed-4f4a-9826-6b3f328466bb.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 196 --terminal-rows 34
[23459 ms] @devcontainers/cli 0.35.0. Node.js v16.14.2. win32 10.0.22621 x64.
[23459 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx version
[24730 ms] github.com/docker/buildx v0.10.4 c513d34049e499c53468deac6c4267ee72948f02
[24730 ms] 
[24731 ms] Start: Resolving Remote
[24743 ms] Start: Run: git rev-parse --show-cdup
[24997 ms] Start: Run: docker ps -q -a --filter label=devcontainer.local_folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --filter label=devcontainer.config_file=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json
[25836 ms] Start: Run: docker inspect --type image debian:bullseye-slim
[26440 ms] local container features stored at: c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\node_modules\vscode-dev-containers\container-features
[26444 ms] Start: Run: tar --no-same-owner -x -f -
[26694 ms] Start: Run: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f C:\Users\Quarks\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.35.0-1681747527877\Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-hello-world-69026d2c7b136982dc155d15b17bc4c1c43ec4fb670b114f9b018261a4881302 --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer

[+] Building 168.6s (7/9)
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile-with-features                                                                                                                             0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 2.78kB                                                                                                                                                         0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                                0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 90B                                                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/debian:bullseye-slim                                                                                                     0.0s
 => CACHED [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 2/5] COPY library-scripts/*.sh /tmp/library-scripts/                                                                                          0.0s
 => ERROR [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 3/5] RUN apt-get update --fix-missing     && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install gnupg     && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian  168.0s
------
 > [dev_container_auto_added_stage_label 3/5] RUN apt-get update --fix-missing     && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install gnupg     && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye main c
ontrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list     && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && echo "deb http://deb.debian
.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update     && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive     && /bin/bash /tmp/library-scripts/common-debian.
sh "true" "vscode" "1000" "1000" "false" "true" "true"    && rm -rf /tmp/library-scripts     && apt-get install -o Acquire::http::Timeout=300 -y --no-install-recommends         dpkg-dev         gc
c         libc6-dev         libffi-dev         libgmp-dev         libnuma-dev         libtinfo-dev         zlib1g-dev     && apt-get autoremove -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/
*:
#0 1.995 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye InRelease [116 kB]
#0 2.532 Get:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security InRelease [48.4 kB]
#0 2.933 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates InRelease [44.1 kB]
#0 3.335 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 Packages [8183 kB]
#0 21.93 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 Packages [237 kB]
#0 22.73 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates/main amd64 Packages [14.6 kB]
#0 25.97 Fetched 8643 kB in 25s (345 kB/s)
#0 25.97 Reading package lists...
#0 27.90 Reading package lists...
#0 32.29 Building dependency tree...
#0 32.93 Reading state information...
#0 33.52 The following additional packages will be installed:
#0 33.52   dirmngr gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client gpg-wks-server
#0 33.52   gpgconf gpgsm libassuan0 libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libncursesw6 libnpth0
#0 33.52   libreadline8 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0 pinentry-curses
#0 33.52   readline-common
#0 33.53 Suggested packages:
#0 33.53   dbus-user-session libpam-systemd pinentry-gnome3 tor parcimonie xloadimage
#0 33.53   scdaemon pinentry-doc readline-doc
#0 33.53 Recommended packages:
#0 33.53   libldap-common libgpm2 libsasl2-modules
#0 34.00 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#0 34.00   dirmngr gnupg gnupg-l10n gnupg-utils gpg gpg-agent gpg-wks-client
#0 34.00   gpg-wks-server gpgconf gpgsm libassuan0 libksba8 libldap-2.4-2 libncursesw6
#0 34.01   libnpth0 libreadline8 libsasl2-2 libsasl2-modules-db libsqlite3-0
#0 34.01   pinentry-curses readline-common
#0 35.58 0 upgraded, 21 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#0 35.58 Need to get 9244 kB of archives.
#0 35.58 After this operation, 19.1 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#0 35.58 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 readline-common all 8.1-1 [73.7 kB]
#0 56.78 Err:2 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libreadline8 amd64 8.1-1
#0 56.78   403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to 151.101.230.132:80: dial tcp 151.101.230.132:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [IP: 151.101.110.132 80]
#0 57.54 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libassuan0 amd64 2.5.3-7.1 [50.5 kB]
#0 72.95 Get:4 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpgconf amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [548 kB]
#0 75.22 Get:5 http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security/main amd64 libksba8 amd64 1.5.0-3+deb11u2 [123 kB]
#0 75.75 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsasl2-modules-db amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1 [69.1 kB]
#0 76.16 Get:7 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsasl2-2 amd64 2.1.27+dfsg-2.1+deb11u1 [106 kB]
#0 76.70 Get:8 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libldap-2.4-2 amd64 2.4.57+dfsg-3+deb11u1 [232 kB]
#0 77.64 Get:9 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libnpth0 amd64 1.6-3 [19.0 kB]
#0 78.05 Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 dirmngr amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [763 kB]
#0 81.65 Get:11 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gnupg-l10n all 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [1086 kB]
#0 84.06 Get:12 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gnupg-utils amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [905 kB]
#0 101.2 Get:13 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libsqlite3-0 amd64 3.34.1-3 [797 kB]
#0 118.2 Get:14 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [928 kB]
#0 121.4 Get:15 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 libncursesw6 amd64 6.2+20201114-2 [132 kB]
#0 122.0 Get:16 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 pinentry-curses amd64 1.1.0-4 [64.9 kB]
#0 143.2 Ign:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-agent amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2
#0 143.7 Get:18 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-wks-client amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [524 kB]
#0 145.1 Get:19 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-wks-server amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [516 kB]
#0 146.6 Get:20 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpgsm amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [645 kB]
#0 163.2 Get:21 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gnupg all 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [825 kB]
#0 166.4 Get:17 http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye/main amd64 gpg-agent amd64 2.2.27-2+deb11u2 [669 kB]
#0 167.9 Fetched 9075 kB in 2min 14s (67.8 kB/s)
#0 167.9 E: Failed to fetch http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/r/readline/libreadline8_8.1-1_amd64.deb  403  connecting to deb.debian.org:80: connecting to 151.101.230.132:80: dial tcp 151.101
.230.132:80: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed
to respond. [IP: 151.101.110.132 80]
#0 167.9 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
------
ERROR: failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c apt-get update --fix-missing     && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install gnupg     && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bulls
eye main contrib non-free" > /etc/apt/sources.list     && echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security bullseye-security main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && echo "deb http://
deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-updates main contrib non-free" >> /etc/apt/sources.list     && apt-get update     && export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive     && /bin/bash /tmp/library-scripts/comm
on-debian.sh "${INSTALL_ZSH}" "${USERNAME}" "${USER_UID}" "${USER_GID}" "${UPGRADE_PACKAGES}" "true" "true"    && rm -rf /tmp/library-scripts     && apt-get install -o Acquire::http::Timeout=300 -
y --no-install-recommends         dpkg-dev         gcc         libc6-dev         libffi-dev         libgmp-dev         libnuma-dev         libtinfo-dev         zlib1g-dev     && apt-get autoremove
 -y && apt-get clean -y && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*]: exit code: 100
[198476 ms] Error: Command failed: docker buildx build --load --build-arg BUILDKIT_INLINE_CACHE=1 -f C:\Users\Quarks\AppData\Local\Temp\devcontainercli\container-features\0.35.0-1681747527877\Dockerfile-with-features -t vsc-hello-world-69026d2c7b136982dc155d15b17bc4c1c43ec4fb670b114f9b018261a4881302 --target dev_containers_target_stage --build-arg _DEV_CONTAINERS_BASE_IMAGE=dev_container_auto_added_stage_label d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer
[198477 ms]     at Sse (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1917:1698)
[198478 ms]     at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
[198478 ms]     at async AD (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1916:3889)
[198479 ms]     at async J7 (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1916:2808)
[198479 ms]     at async $se (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1931:2626)
[198480 ms]     at async Ah (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:1931:3741)
[198480 ms]     at async aae (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2059:17376)
[198481 ms]     at async oae (c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js:2059:17117)
[198524 ms] Exit code 1
[198533 ms] Command failed: C:\Users\Quarks\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe --ms-enable-electron-run-as-node c:\Users\Quarks\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers-0.288.1\dist\spec-node\devContainersSpecCLI.js up --user-data-folder c:\Users\Quarks\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\globalStorage\ms-vscode-remote.remote-containers\data --container-session-data-folder /tmp/devcontainers-dd392877-a03c-41f6-93bd-5777b1a35b8f1681747497325 --workspace-folder d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --workspace-mount-consistency cached --id-label devcontainer.local_folder=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world --id-label devcontainer.config_file=d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --log-level debug --log-format json --config d:\Codes\haskell\hello-world\.devcontainer\devcontainer.json --default-user-env-probe loginInteractiveShell --mount type=volume,source=vscode,target=/vscode,external=true --mount type=bind,source=\\wsl.localhost\Ubuntu\mnt\wslg\runtime-dir\wayland-0,target=/tmp/vscode-wayland-70e6c119-04ed-4f4a-9826-6b3f328466bb.sock --skip-post-create --update-remote-user-uid-default on --mount-workspace-git-root true --terminal-columns 196 --terminal-rows 34
[198534 ms] Exit code 1
```

Pardon the verbosity of this post, but I wanted to share the whole config and logs. What could be the root problem why this dev container keeps on failing?